# Changing default wp_nav_menu classes

Tags: wordpress

The wp_nav_menu produces default classes for the `<div>` and `<ul>` producing the following ....

```
<div class="menu-horizontal-container">
    <ul id="menu-horizontal" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

... but I want to change the classes and IDs to the following .... how can this be done?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="main_navigation_menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I could be wrong but this seems more like a CSS issue. Ie, change the CSS for each ID/Class rather than trying to change what the nav function is generating. From what I know that is a bit beyond the scope of what we can instruct here because its more like you need a developer to do it for you.

Comment: @GaryCarlyleCook .... the wp_nav_menu function generates the id's and classes in the first example above ... it's not as straightforward as keeping those classes/id's and changing the style because there is also JQuery dynamically making changes to some ... so I prefer to alter the class/id names. Nathan below has provided the answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution which combines the contributions from @Oleg and @Nathan with two possible outputs ... also the important thing was declaring the theme ***location*** rather than the menu name.

**OUTPUT A - without the Walker_Nav_Menu function**

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location'      => 'primary',
    'container'           => 'div',
    'container_class'     => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'menu_class'          => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
    'menu_id'             => 'main_navigation_menu',
)) ;
```

*produced:*

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul id="main_navigation_menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**OUTPUT B - with the Walker_Nav_Menu function BUT changing 'echo' to TRUE in the parameters:**

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location'      => 'primary',
    'container'           => 'div',
    'container_class'     => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'menu_class'          => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
    'menu_id'             => 'main_navigation_menu',
    'echo'                => true,
    'walker'              => new Walker_Custom_Menu,
)) ;
```

*produced:*

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul id="main_navigation_menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#/">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks @Oleg and @Nathan.

Answer (score 1):

Add it where you want to display menu.

```
$menuParameters = array(
    'theme_location'      => 'header-menu',
    'container'           => 'div',
    'container_class'     => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'menu_class'          => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
    'menu_id'             => 'main_navigation_menu',
    'echo'                => false,
    'walker'              => new Walker_Custom_Menu,
);
```

Add walker to function.php

```
class Walker_Custom_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
   /**
    * Start the element output.
    *
    * @see Walker::start_el()
    *
    * @since 3.0.0
    * @since 4.4.0 'nav_menu_item_args' filter was added.
    *
    * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
    * @param object $item   Menu item data object.
    * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
    * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
    * @param int    $id     Current item ID.
    */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        /**
         * Filter the arguments for a single nav menu item.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param array  $args  An array of arguments.
         * @param object $item  Menu item data object.
         * @param int    $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

        /**
         * Filter the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array  $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param object $item    The current menu item.
         * @param array  $args    An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
         * @param int    $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Filter the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.1
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param object $item    The current menu item.
         * @param array  $args    An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
         * @param int    $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        /**
         * Filter the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
         *
         * @since 3.6.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array $atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
         *     @type string $target Target attribute.
         *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
         *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
         * }
         * @param object $item  The current menu item.
         * @param array  $args  An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
         * @param int    $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        /**
         * Filter a menu item's title.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param string $title The menu item's title.
         * @param object $item  The current menu item.
         * @param array  $args  An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
         * @param int    $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        /**
         * Filter a menu item's starting output.
         *
         * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
         * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
         * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
         * @param object $item        Menu item data object.
         * @param int    $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param array  $args        An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
         */
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the parameters you pass in to `wp_nav_menu`. In particular you need to set 'menu_class', 'menu_id' and 'container_class'.

Example:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location'  => 'menu-horizontal', 
    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    . . .
) );
```

Further reading: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/